# Webdriver - Open context menu at specific coordinates

Tags: ruby, webdriver, contextmenu

I have a big canvas area, which have different context menu action for different parts of this area.
So i need to perform context menu click with specific coordinates.

In documentation I only found this function:

```
element = @@driver.find_element(:xpath, xpath_value)
@@driver.action.context_click(element).perform
```

But I cannot specify coordinates for this context click. It's works, but only in center of canvas area.

Is there any other way to open context menu?
I also tried openen it from keyboard, but my test page doesn't support context menu by pressing "Shift" + F10, only by pressing "Menu Key" from keyboard.
Can I perfrom press on Menu Key on keyboard from WebDriver?

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'win32ole'

require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to('http://www.elmcomputers.com/Shortcut_Keys.pdf')

skey = WIN32OLE.new('Wscript.Shell')

skey.SendKeys('+{F10}') #SHIFT+f10
```

Tested and working. Try with your page see what happens. I know you mentioned that it won't accept the key combo but I think this has to do with Windows and not the page itself. Have a look..

Comment: Menu key - key on keyboard, to the left from right "Control". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key Sorry, I cannot post a website, because it's internal of our company

Comment: Ok no pro. So you still need help? I can post you the code on how to simulate a 'windows-key' stroke.. You still want it?

Comment: Sorry, i think you didn't understand - I don't need an 'Windows' key press. I need a 'Menu' key press. It's the key that's looks like this: http://peltiertech.com/images/2009-08/KeyboardBottomRight.jpg

Comment: Try now with the revised code I've posted above..ALT+(HYPHEN) is what you need I think..see if it works..I don't have this key in my keyboard..How can I test it that is working? Can I for example open MS word and press it and what should happen?

Comment: It's open context menu just like Right Mouse Click in place, there cursor is.

Comment: I was trying to find the ASCII code for you..Manual says {ASC nnnn} will send chars according to ascii code but me still I didn't manage to send anything this way. I'm guessing it is working now, using the good old SHIFT+F10? :)

Comment: Nah, web app which I'm testing doesn't support SHIFT+F10. This was the trouble in first place :) So anyway - seems we have no answer for it, so i added issue for Webdriver tracker - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4296

Comment: I'm still looking for a way to hit on SHIFT+f10 but by using ASCII..maybe it will still not be possible but it is definitely worth a try..Meanwhile can you think of any alternative route to your problem? i.e. not using the context menu but somewhat different, or is it the only way? Also it will be useful to know (if you know of course) HOW the page is prohibiting SHIFT+F10, are these buttons disabled when u visit the page? thanks :)